# Django Allauth and Google

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've tried to add google login to my web application using django-allauth.

I added to my google application the following callback_uri:

```
"http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback"
```

since i'm running tests on my development server (localhost) and i don't wanna use https.

Even though, i get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch' saying that my redirect URI doesn't match any registred redirect URI.

Does anyone have any ideea about what causes this?

Thanks for your time.

Later Edit:

Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into problems trying to get Google+ to work as well. I finally got it working. I made some updates to the documentation so it's a bit easier to use. See if using the [updated allauth google docs](https://github.com/RRMoelker/django-allauth/blob/master/docs/providers.rst#google) you can get it to work.

Comment: The problem was that for some odd reasons google app requires 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost if you try to use the app in a development enviroment. Also, I had to access the site through 127.0.0.1 for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try doing the following:
1. Go to the Google Developers console -> Api $ auth -> credentials 
2. You should see "Client ID for web application" click "Edit Settings" 
3. Change your "Redirect URI" to "http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback"

Should work after that let me know if it doesn't.

Cheers,

Dan